Treynor and Black (1973) Equation 13 usefulness
Equation (13) in Treynor and Black How to Use Security Analysis to Improve Portfolio Selection (1973) gives the optimal weights using the formula:

In practice, I have seen the rightmost fraction calculated as:

But where does this come from? Equation (11) states that:

And also:

So dividing those equations leaves the lambda. The best I can do is equation (19) where:

So how do I prove that?


The $h_i$ have to add up to $1$. Does that help?

My question is: how does the rightmost fraction in equation (13), as it is usually calculated in practice, follow from the variable definitions given in equation (11) (or am I missing something)?

First of all eqn (13) is $h_i=\frac{\mu_i}{\sigma^2_i}\frac{\sigma^2_p}{\mu_p}$. Let's call the second fraction on the right K, a number which we don't know. We do know that $\sum_i h_i = 1$ so $\sum_i h_i = K\sum_i \frac{\mu_i}{\sigma^2_i}=1$ So $1/K=\sum_i \frac{\mu_i}{\sigma^2_i}$ and $h_i= \frac{\mu_i}{\sigma^2_i} /\sum_j \frac{\mu_j}{\sigma^2_j}$ where all terms on the right side are known.

Solved. Thank you very much. Please post an Answer so I can give you some points. Also, just wondering why the change in subscript from i to j?

That's a computer programming technicality, we are already using the variable $i$ so we need anothe variable $j$ which is "bound" to the summation sign, it is like a "do-loop" variable nested within a code block that uses $i$ for a different purpose. If you are comfortable with using "i" throughout that's fine, a compiler might not like it.

Treynor and Black clearly mention that they optimize the portfolio under the constraint $$\mu_p=
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}h_i\mu_i$$ being constant. I cannot see anywhere in their paper the assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}h_i$ must be one.
